# Does MS IGLOO take place before or after the first Mobile Suit Gundam?

Tags: mobile-suit-gundam

The Gundam Wiki says that MS IGLOO is chronologically before the First Gundam. But there was a list in here saying that after the First Gundam, there followed 08th MS Team, then War in the Pocket, and THEN the three MS IGLOO OVA series.

Can you help a fellow Gundam brother out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This series takes place before and alongside the original Gundam, followed by 08th, then 0080, then 0083, then Z, then ZZ, then CCA.

The events of the MS IGLOO series encompass everything from the development of mobile suits and the Battle of Loum all the way to Odessa, which is the beginning of the end of the One Year War from Gundam's Universal Century timeline

08th MS team starts sometime during the war and definitely after the start of MS Igloo, since 08th MS Team starts with The Federation having not just mobile suits, but the RX-79[G] which was a new type of Gundam.